# Phonegap-Blackberry backpress issue/how to handle back key in phonegap

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator

when i pressed back key using blackberry simulator then its close my whole application but when i pressed back button which i provided in header then its working fine.how to solved this is? is there any backpress handing in phonegap?  Same code for android works fine means it doesn't close application on back key press.

Comment: Please any one have idea about this then give any suggestion. Because same code runs on other platform but in blackberry application exist directly.

Answer (score 0):

Or
`<script type="text/javascript">`
`// Wait for PhoneGap to load`
`//`
`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`
`// PhoneGap is ready`
`//`
`function onDeviceReady() {`
`blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK,` 
`function() {`
`history.back();`
`return false;`
`});`
`}`
`</script>`

Answer (score -1):

On config.xml --> `<feature id="blackberry.system.event" version="1.0.0"/>`